# Locust: how to specify a get request who takes query parameter

Tags: python, locust

I want to load test my get request which is

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/synonyms/project/?keyword=dealer
```

and test method is

```
@task(2)
def get_synonym(self):
    response = self.client.get("/v1/synonyms/project/")
    print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response content:", response.text)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pass the query string in the url:

`response = self.client.get("/v1/synonyms/project/?keyword=dealer")`

Comment: is there a simple way to pass empty value to a query parameter via locust. 
As the below is not working and is giving a 400 bad request giving message
 Message: Required String parameter 'keyword2' is not present
`response = self.client.get("/v1/synonyms/project/?keyword1=&keyword2=abc")`